# Avoid using dynamic table names, but how?

Tags: database, database-design, logic

I am new to database design and I'm trying to get into the best practices early. So far everywhere I look their seems to be an agreement that you "Create the table names at the start of development, and insert your data, do *not* use variables for table names. Well I was looking to make an asset management system and I can't get past what seems like a design flaw. This software would be very similar to "quickbase" if you're familiar.

Here is the scenario.

- User can create accounts, each account is in a table of accounts that has data inside that links back to the other related tables.
- Inside each account there is as many catagories as they need to track info such as:

  - Financials
  - Trips
  - Tasks
  - etc

Now each one of these categories would hold a significant amount of information and would require it's own table. Obviously I could use relationships to connect these tables back to the account but their is a problem (I think). The user can create as many accounts as they need and every time they do their will need to be a number of other tables created along with it. Such as "account_name_financials_table" etc.

So my question is: Can this be possible to do without using variables for table names when dynamically creating them. *OR* is this a scenario where it would be considered acceptable to use variables for table names when creating them.

If this is too localized or vague please let me know and I will provide any further details needed.

Thank you for your time

**EDIT**

In response to Davids awesome answer.

I fully understand now that each account is actually just an entry, or a row into one table that would hold the information for each account. The column names would then describe the data that describes my account and subsequently relates to the other tables.

Now the core of this problem is that when I create the account there are other tables that *need* to be created, or at least I think they do. This would be a financials table for instance that holds specific information about that accounts financials. There is a one to one relationship on these tables. Meaning Account A can only have 1 set of financials for the specific account. So when I create Account B the financials table I currently have would no longer have relevant column names, rows, or data for Account B. So when I create these new tables for Account B, they would more then likely need to be done dynamically. With this being said, how would I create them without variable names?

Or perhaps I'm still missing the point. A thought occurs to me that perhaps I could have one large financial table that holds information for all accounts and that information is defined/related back to the specific account by 'id' or some other unique fk pk identifier?

Comment: `"each account is its own table"` - You lost me right there.  Why does each account need its own table?  Shouldn't there be a table of Accounts and then tables of data related to Accounts which have foreign keys back to that table?

Comment: @David You're correct I definitely misspoke there I would have 1 table with Account Information and then the data inside would link back to the other related tables. I edited my question to better reflect my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of a table as an entity in your domain, think of it as a definition of the what describes an entity and each record in that table is an instance of that entity.

Given that, this statement becomes incorrect:

> User can create accounts, each account is its own table.

The `Account` (or `Accounts`, depending on your naming conventions) table is the schematic definition of what describes an Account entity.  It might have columns like the Account's name, the date it registered, things like that.  Each record in the `Account` table is an Account.  So there would be one `Account` table which holds all of the Accounts in the domain.

> Inside each account there is 4 - 8 catagories they can track

That statement seems a little counterintuitive to describe relational data.  How about:

> Each Account can also have additional data related to it, such as...

And now the next lines aren't describing something that's "inside" an Account, but rather another entity in the domain which happens to *relate* to an Account:

- Financials
- Trips
- Tasks
- etc.

Each of these is an entity in its own right (or can be anyway, the terms currently are a little vague) which don't necessarily *describe* an Account, but themselves are *described by* an Account.  That is, an Account doesn't point to a Task.  A Task points to an Account.  The Account itself is a data point which describes the Task.

Thus, each of these becomes tables in their own right, in which the records have foreign keys back to the `Account` table.  Something as simple as this:

```
Task
----------------------
ID          | int
AccountID   | int
Description | nvarchar
ScheduledOn | datetime
```

And so on.  Each record in that table (each record represents one Task in the domain) would include an `AccountID` value which indicates which Account owns that Task.

The tables should be specific to any particular subset of entities, but should be general to all instances of that particular entity.

You can further customize entities into different types by sub-typing tables.  For example, maybe you have different kinds of Accounts and there are different fields which describe them.  You might have a single `Account` table as above, but would have additional tables where the primary key is also the foreign key to the `Account` table.  These tables would represent one-to-one relationships to the `Account` table and could add more values to a "subset" of Accounts.  A table like this, for example:

```
PreferredAccount
---------------------
AccountID       | int (PK, also FK to Account.ID)
PreferredStatus
BecamePreferredOn
```

And so on.  That way you can logically separate your Accounts by type without having to create multiple tables to represent an Account itself.

To get back to the question... **Ultimately, when a user creates an Account, they're not changing the schema of the database.  They're simply adding a record to the `Account` table.**

Comment: thank you very much sir. I do appreciate the effort and this helps me visualize my problem in a better light, please see the edit to my question as it is the core of my problem.

Comment: @i_me_mine: I think you might be missing the notion of what a foreign key accomplishes for tables.  You don't need Account A and Account B to have their own table of Financials.  You'd have a single `Financials` table where one of the columns is a foreign key to the `Accounts` table.  So each record in the `Financials` table would have a field indicating which `Account` it relates to.  So in the `Task` table in my answer, each record has an `AccountID` value which points back to the `Account` record it belongs to.  So all Accounts would use the same Tasks table (or Financials table, etc.).

Comment: that actually makes perfect sense. So its one table to rule them all then eh? I like it. So just create however many tables I need with the proper relationships and then I should never have to dynamically create a table for the rest of the time I'm developing. Thank you for turning someone who was clueless into someone a little more educated!